# An example where $E[X_1 X_2] - E[X_1]E[X_2] = 0$ for functions $X_1$ and $X_2$

Tags: statistics

I computed $E[X_1 X_2] - E[X_1]E[X_2]$ using $X_1 = 3x+1$ and $X_2 = 2x+5$ the following way:

$E[(3x+1)(2x+5)] - E[3x+1]E[2x+5] = E[6x^2 + 17x + 5] - (3E[x]+1)(2E[x]+5) = 6(E[x^2] - E^2[x]) = 6\sigma^2$

When I was done I asked myself when does $E[x^2] = E^2[x]$ for some functions $X_1$ and $X_2$? But I couldn't think of a good example. I also wondered why I didn't get zero since $X_1$ and $X_2$ appear to be independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you mean $X$ is a random variable (most people would use a capital letter here), and $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the random variables defined by $X_1 = 3X+1$ and $X_2=2X+5$.  The answer to your question is that $E(X^2)-E(X)^2 =0$ if and only if $X$ is a constant.  This is because $E(X^2)-E(X)^2$ is the variance of $X$. And if $X$ is a constant, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are constants, and if you look carefully at the definition of independence, you'll find this implies $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

So, if $E(X^2)-E(X)^2 \neq 0$, then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent.  You wouldn't expect them to be, anyway (unless $X$ is constant), since one is an affine function of the other.

Answer (score 1):

When they are independent. See [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).